# Delete all files and folder except two folders using command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I want to delete all files and folders in `My Documents\someapp\data` except two folders namely **data** and **settings**.

I am really new to this.

Comment: Is this a one off activity or something you want to do regularly?

Comment: Not regular but need to send it to my friends as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

- Move the two directories somewhere safe
- Delete the remaining files and directories
- Move the two directories back again.

Something like:

```
md "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\save"
move "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\someapp\data\data" "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\save\data"
move "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\someapp\data\settings" "\%USERPROFILE%My Documents\save\settings"
del /f /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\someapp\data"
md "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\someapp\data"
move "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\save\data" "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\someapp\data\data" 
move "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\save\settings" "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\someapp\data\settings"
rd "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\save"
```

Notes:

- The `"`s are required because the directory names contain `space`.
- Using `%USERPROFILE%` allows the same commands to work on your friend's computers.
- You could put all of these commands in a batch file to send to your friends.

Comment: Thanks it works, but it still leaves unwanted empty folders in that directory like cache,temp,crash report etc.I don't even want those empty folders.

Comment: @Ronnie Try `del /f /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\someapp\data\*` and see if the empty directories go as well

Comment: @Ronnie Note I've added `%USERPROFILE%` everywhere to the original answer to make it more portable.

Comment: It didn't work, still leaves empty folders and sub folders.I used the updated code itself.

Comment: Updated script to remove complete data directory and recreate it before copying back. Please try the **complete script** again.

Comment: Same problem with the updated one as well.Thanks for the efforts I think it does what was needed.Will send to my friends.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/1180871/379513

Comment: @MatthewWai Cool trick :)