# How can I delete "D:\Folder\" without deleting "D:\Folder\file.txt"?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

This is used in a cmd file: `rmdir /s /q "D:\Folder\"`

How can I delete `D:\Folder\` without deleting `D:\Folder\file.txt`?

Comment: have a look on [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/hu-hu/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx). I don't have much experience with it, but it should work for you: `/move /nodd` switches performs delete `/a`  includes only files of which archive attribute is set (select all files, set archive attribute, then select the files you want to keep and remove attribute)

Comment: Still confused --- Is the end goal to delete everything INSIDE D:\Folder\*.* except: File.TXT? or the Delete THIS folder D:\Folder\ and LEAVE at least: File.TXT file?  If the latter, what folder would then contain your file?

Comment: @DaaBoss: the goal is to delete everything INSIDE `D:\Folder\` except `file.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redirect the file as input stream to lock it so it can not be deleted

```dos
<"d:\folder\file.txt" rmdir /s /q "d:\folder"
```

Comment: Bingo! It works. Thank you very much, MC ND.

Comment: What if I want to lock "D:\folder\sub folder\" so that it cannot be deleted?

Comment: @MatthewWai, if you only want to protect the folder itself (not its contents) you only need to set it as the current active directory (`cd /d d:\folder\subfolder`). If you want to protect its contents, then `rmdir /s` "as is" is not your command.

Comment: I want to protect the subfolder and its contents. What is the complete command?

Comment: @MatthewWai, you need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30566707/2861476)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Windows PowerShell with the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Folder\" | Where-Object { $_.FullName -ne "D:\Folder\file.txt" } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my question incorrectly. The excluded folder should have been an excluded file.

Comment: @MatthewWai Duly noted.